# Is there any opnions that can execute scripts provided by user and have not safety impact on existing systems

Tags: python, security, restrict

I'm developing a data analysis sofware running on Linux, writing by Python; One of the requirements is that when data match some conditions, the software will generate an alert log, and user can provide a Shell script or Python script to process the alert log. The problem is that user may write some malicious code to access and destory the system, so I dont want the user gain the ability to access filesystem or network or privileges, that means all scripts provide by user is restricted, Is there anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!